# How to get values from HTML select option list

Tags: forms, form-submit, onsubmit

`<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="select1">
        <option value="value1">Value one</option>
        <option value="value2">Value two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
</form>`

Onsubmit, i need to print `Value one` on submit. All the posts are using `$_POST['select1']` to get the value. But it will only give `value1`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
function changeValue(){

var e = document.getElementById("select1");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("submit").value = strUser;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post">
  <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="value1">Value one</option>
    <option value="value2">Value two</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go" onclick="changeValue();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: `function changeValue(){
var e = document.getElementById("select1");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
document.getElementById("member-value").value = strUser;
} `   i tried `<div id="member-value" class="pager-left"></div>`. But the `div` didn't got value after submit

Comment: @drup: use <span id="member-value" class="pager-left"></span>

Comment: @drup for div use innerHtml not value.  document.getElementById("member-value").innerHTML  = strUser;

Comment: Is there any way to get it with PHP instead of javascript. I need to retain the value without any lose during page load.

Comment: @drup You can't do this with PHP alone. You need some javascript also try using this     <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="document.getElementById('member-value').innerHTML=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text">